# imap error after received Gimap ready for requests

Tags: imap

I have an error when i run the code.

the following is the code:

```
void smtp_listener::imapLogin(QString reply)
{
    print_D(FUNC);
    print_D(QString("this is "+reply+"well"));
    if(reply.contains("OK"))
    {
        QString msg = QString("user %1").arg(user);
        print_D(msg);
        *t << msg <<"\r\r\n";
        t->flush();
        setState(POP3_Pass);
    }
    else
    {
        print_E("ERROR :"+reply,FUNC,__LINE__);
        quitConn();
        setState(POP3_Quit);
    }
}

void smtp_listener::pop3Pass(QString reply)
{
    print_D(FUNC);
    print_D(QString("this is "+reply+" well"));
    if(reply.contains("+OK"))
    {
        QString msg = QString("pass %1").arg(pass);
        *t << msg <<"\r\n";
        t->flush();

        setState(POP3_Stat);
    }
    else
    {
        print_E("ERROR :"+reply,FUNC,__LINE__);
        quitConn();
        setState(POP3_Quit);
    }
}
```

the error i give after i debug:

> [Debug]  "Email account : connected."
>
> [Debug]  "void smtp_listener::imapLogin(QString)"
>
> [Debug]  "this is * OK Gimap ready for requests from 140.101.159.251
>   q2-v6mb85227685wrd
>
> well"
>
> [Debug]  "user chairouyih@gmail.com"
>
> [Debug]  "void smtp_listener::pop3Pass(QString)"
>
> [Debug]  "this is user BAD Unknown command q2-v6mb85227685wrd
>
> well"
>
> "[Error] ERROR :user BAD Unknown command q2-v6mb85227685wrd
>
> at func=void smtp_listener::pop3Pass(QString) Line=361"
>
> [Debug]  "void smtp_listener::quitConn()"
>
> [Debug]  "void smtp_listener::pop3Quit(QString)"
>
> [Debug]  "* BAD invalid tag q2-v6mb85227685wrd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using POP3 commands with an IMAP server.  They are not compatible, and their language is very different.

For one, every IMAP command has a tag, and basic logging in is done with a LOGIN command.  It would look something like this:

```
a001 LOGIN user@gmail.com "password"
```

If you want to use POP3, connect to the pop3 server at pop.gmail.com, with TLS enabled on port 995.

Comment: Sorry, can u explain it more?

Comment: They are different protocols. POP and IMAP are superficially similar but have profoundly different details. Your frequent flyer card may look like your bank card, but the details differ and you really can't use the frequent flyer card to withdraw cash from an ATM.

Comment: @YihAshley If you're going to do IMAP from scratch, you really need to read RFC 3501.

Comment: a error message state that " CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- SPECIAL-USE APPENDLIMIT=35651584 a001 OK chairouyih@gmail.com authenticated (Success)" after i change to imap commands. Is it mean that the imap run successful?

Comment: a001 OK means yes, it was successful.  a001 matches the tag you sent, and OK is a success code.  Other possible codes are `NO`, which means the command did not succeed, and `BAD` which means it did not understand your command.

Comment: Means you used a malformed tag before your command.  Every command has a tag, and it must be alphanumeric.